# lock.lock() before try

Tags: java, locking, java.util.concurrent

Is there any difference between:

```
private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

public void getIn (int direction) throws InterruptedException {

     lock.lock();
     try {
         ...
```

and

```
...

public void getIn (int direction) throws InterruptedException {

      try {
          lock.lock();
          ...
```

Compilation goes smoothly and also the program works (I mean the same output)

Should I put lock.lock(); before or after try?...

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is caught? If you later catch `ExceptionThatLockCannotThrow` - there isn't really any difference between them

Comment: A few statemen before: private Lock lock; and then lock=new ReentrantLock(true); thanks...the unlocking operation is done at the end through; finally } lock.unlock();

Answer (score 26):

Assuming that `lock` is a [`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), then it makes no real difference, since [`lock()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#lock%28%29) does not throw any checked exceptions.

The Java documentation, however, leaves `lock()` outside the `try` block in the `ReentrantLock` example. The reason for this is that an *unchecked* exception in `lock()` should not lead to `unlock()` incorrectly being called. Whether correctness is a concern in the presence of an unchecked exception in `lock()` of all things, that is another discussion altogether.

It is a good coding practice in general to keep things like `try` blocks as fine-grained as possible.

Answer (score 11):

If case No 1, in `finally` you can just say `unlock()`. In case No2 you need to check if you are holding the lock before `unlock()`, otherwise you can get `IllegalMonitorStateException`

Comment: You should expand on why this is the case. I think this could be the best answer to this question with some explanation.

Answer (score 7):

The try statement also contains:

```
 } finally {
     lock.unlock();
 }
```

That is, if you place `lock.lock()` after `try`, exceptions thrown by  `lock.lock()` would cause 
`lock.unlock()`, which is wrong, because lock was not obtained, and unlocking would cause another exception. So the first variant is correct. To handle exceptions thrown by `lock.lock()` you have to use another try statement.

Answer (score 0):

In first case: if the `lock.lock()` throws `InterruptedException`, `getIn` will manage it. But for any other exception, it would throw an exception, which `getIn` doesn't handles : Runtime Exception

In second case: apart from `InterruptedException`, the `try-catch` block is also doing some exception handling, which you have not shown here. This should throw lesser exceptions, as the inner block is also capturing some exceptions.

The overall running depends on what exceptions `lock.lock()` throws?

Comment: The method [`lock()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#lock--) does not throw InterruptedExceptions. The block in the `getIn` method is actually a `try-finally` block, not a `try-catch` one.